# IntelliJ does not show "Applications" as an option in Run/Debug Configurations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am watching a tutorial on how to make minecraft mods for 1.15.2/1.16.3. The program used to write the code and manage the files is IntelliJ. I have watched this [episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOTH1eDP99Y&list=PLDhiRTZ_vnoUI3-9z0Zg-I8tTSp3EfOia&ab_channel=TechnoVision) in which he shows how to add the "applications" tab to the Run/Debug Configuration window. The applications tab does not show up for me. A solution he gave in the video was to reload the disk, but it does not work for me. I need another way to get the application tab that allows me to run the client.

Answer (score 1):

So, after asking in other forums, I got this answer.
I forgot to run "gradlew genIntellijRuns". To do this, follow these steps:

1. Open Command Prompt
2. Go to the file location where your mod folder is held
3. Type in "gradlew genIntellijRuns" and wait about a minute.
   After these steps you can restart IntelliJ and the tab will show up.